# Is there a way to save progress of TCP packet transfer when a connection is dropped?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I apologize if this question is stupid or if this is actually a thing. Here is a scenario:

You're trying to exchange TCP packets while dealing with low-bandwidth communication between a desktop and RPi. Say that halfway during transmission of a particular packet, the connection drops. So the receiver of that packet only receives half of it.

Is there a way that the sender of the packet to know that only a portion of the packet is received, and thus send the remaining lost portion of the packet so that the receiving end is able to fully create the original packet?

Again, please take it easy on me haha this was just a really curious question.

Edit: I believe I can also realize that this would require the additional sending of packets to convey that only part of the packet has been received, so please point out that from a optimization standpoint if that is pointless.

Comment: The frame would be damaged, so it would be dropped at the data-link layer, never getting  the packet to the network layer, which prevents it from sending the segment to the transport layer (TCP). TCP would never see see a segment from half a frame.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense. We are dealing with a project that has to really optimize the transfer of packets and so I was just curious on that front. Thank you so much!